# gulp-sass sometime not working in gulp.watch

Tags: gulp, gulp-watch, gulp-sass

```js
'use strict'

const gulp = require('gulp'),
      sass = require('gulp-sass'),
      sourceMap = require("gulp-sourcemaps");

gulp.task('sassToCss', ()=>{
    return gulp.src("scss/application.scss")
        .pipe(sourceMap.init())
            .pipe(sass())
        .pipe(sourceMap.write('./'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('css'));
});

gulp.task('watchFile', ()=>{
    gulp.watch('scss/**/*.scss', ['sassToCss']);
});
```

when I use (gulp sassToCss) it always work.But when i start (gulp watchFile) and 
edit some file in sass folder it's sometime work and sometime not. and which file i change it's give the error that this file can't find.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mA4N2.jpg)